# Scrapy - NameError: name 'items' is not defined

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to fill my Items with parsed data and I'm getting error:

```
item = items()

NameError: name 'items' is not defined**
```

When I run `scrapy crawl usa_florida_scrapper`

Here's my spider's code:

```
import scrapy
import re

class UsaFloridaScrapperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name            = 'usa_florida_scrapper'
    start_urls      = ['https://www.txlottery.org/export/sites/lottery/Games/index.html']    

    def parse(self, response):    
        item = items()      
        
        print('++++++ Latest Results for Powerball  ++++++++++')
        power_ball_html = (response.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/ol").extract_first())
        power_balls=(",".join(re.findall(r'<span>(.+)</span>',power_ball_html)))
        power_ball_special=(response.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/ol/li[6]/span[contains(@class, 'powerball')]/text()").get())        
        power_ball_jackpot = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/h1/text()').get()
        power_ball_multiplier = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/h3/span/text()').get()
        
        item['LotteryKey']= '227'
        item['Date']= '2020-10-10'
        item['Balls']= power_balls
        item['SpecialBalls']= power_ball_special
        item['Multiplier']= power_ball_multiplier
        item['JackpotValue']= power_ball_jackpot
        
        
        yield item
```

Here's my items code items.py:

```
import scrapy

class KariedanielItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    LotteryKey = scrapy.Field()
    Date = scrapy.Field()
    Balls = scrapy.Field()
    SpecialBalls = scrapy.Field()
    Multiplier = scrapy.Field()
    JackpotValue = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to instantiate something called `items()` that doesn't exist anywhere in your code.

```
def parse(self, response):    
    item = items()
```

If you defined your Item class to be `KariedanielItem`, then that's what you need to instantiate.

```
def parse(self, response):    
    item = KariedanielItem()
```

Remember, you will also need to import that class into the spider.

```
from your_project.items import KariedanielItem
```

*`your_project` here is a placeholder*

Answer (score 0):

First import your item class at top, replace your_project_name with your scrapy project name.

```
from your_project_name.items import KariedanielItem
```

Next replace this line **`item = items()`** with **`item = FeboughtItem()`** in **`parse`** function.

your code will be like this,

```
import scrapy
import re
from your_project_name.items import KariedanielItem

class UsaFloridaScrapperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name            = 'usa_florida_scrapper'
    start_urls      = ['https://www.txlottery.org/export/sites/lottery/Games/index.html']    

    def parse(self, response):    
        item = KariedanielItem()      
        
        print('++++++ Latest Results for Powerball  ++++++++++')
        power_ball_html = (response.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/ol").extract_first())
        power_balls=(",".join(re.findall(r'<span>(.+)</span>',power_ball_html)))
        power_ball_special=(response.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/ol/li[6]/span[contains(@class, 'powerball')]/text()").get())        
        power_ball_jackpot = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/h1/text()').get()
        power_ball_multiplier = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/h3/span/text()').get()
        
        item['LotteryKey']= '227'
        item['Date']= '2020-10-10'
        item['Balls']= power_balls
        item['SpecialBalls']= power_ball_special
        item['Multiplier']= power_ball_multiplier
        item['JackpotValue']= power_ball_jackpot
        
        
        yield item
```